# Can you heal yourself while you are at 0 HP?

Tags: dnd-5e, healing, unconscious

I just found [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/34170/42158) and I find it very interesting, but it's about D&D 3e. I want to know if this still applies in D&D 5e. I'll quote the question:

> If my understanding of the rules is correct, at 0 HP you are still aware and can take certain actions, but taking a strenuous standard action such as attacking or casting a spell will drop you to -1 HP and render you unconscious. If you use that action to cast a healing spell on yourself, does that just drop you to -1 HP and waste the spell, or does it put you back into positive HP?

I *think* (I'm new in this) that it wouldn't work, right? I read that when you get 0 HP you are unconcious in D&D 5e instead of aware. Is that true?

Comment: I recommend reading the PHB. Or the SRD.

Comment: The rules related to being at zero hp and unconsciousness changed **a lot** from 3.X to 5e. You should focus on the 5e rules to understand how it works in 5e.

Comment: The various D&D are basically different games using the same name. It's better to assume that *nothing* is the same. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## A creature at 0 hp is unconscious and unable to take actions

The rules on dropping to 0hp (found in the Player's Handbook or Basic Rules) say:

> When you drop to 0 hit points, you either die outright or fall unconscious ([D&DBeyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Droppingto0HitPoints))

[Unconscious](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Unconcious) is a condition in the game which is defined as:

> An unconscious creature is incapacitated, can't move or speak, and is unaware of its surroundings

Being unconscious also means you are [Incapacitated](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Incapacitated), which is another condition. It is defined as:

> An incapacitated creature can't take actions or reactions.

Thus, a creature at 0 hp cannot take actions or reactions because they are incapacitated.

## There is no current way to heal yourself without actions or reactions while unconscious (without preparation beforehand)

The vast majority of forms of healing that I am aware of (spells, potions, abilities) involve someone taking an action or reaction or bonus action. Since you can take none of those while unconscious, there are very few ways if any for an unconscious person to heal themselves.

#### Using the spell Contingency <sup>1</sup>

[Contingency](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/contingency) is a spell that allows you to precast a spell and apply a condition that dictates when the spell will take effect. It is a costly spell and takes preparation. But if you used a healing spell with a condition of "when I drop unconscious" or something similar it could heal you while you were unconscious.

## There are some specific exceptions to this

A Zealot Barbarian gets the feature Rage beyond Death at Level 14 which reads:

> Beginning at 14th level, the divine power that fuels your rage allows
> you to shrug off fatal blows. While you’re raging, having 0 hit points
> doesn’t knock you unconscious. ([Xanathar's Guide to Everything p. 11](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/barbarian#PathoftheZealot))

The character with this ability would not be unconscious at 0 hp and could thus heal in whatever way they were able. But this is a specific class ability and is a specific exception to the general rules above.

## The rules of 5e have changed significantly from previous editions

As a general rule, just assume that nothing is the same between editions of D&D, it saves a lot of confusion down the road.

The only way to learn 5e is by using the 5e materials. Getting a copy of the Player's Handbook should provide a great resource for learning. You can peruse the basic rules online as well [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules) for free.

---

<sup>1</sup> Thanks @Tenryu.

Comment: PHB p. 189 states "You choose when to take a bonus action during your turn, unless the bonus action’s timing is specified, and anything that deprives you of your ability to take actions also prevents you from taking a bonus action." Therefore, you couldn't cast *Healing Word* regardless of its components.

Comment: @PixelMaster: Excellent catch. I knew there had to be something besides the V component that prevented it (it just doesn't make sense). I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose There is a current way to heal yourself while unconscious: Contingency. Using it with a spell like False Life would get you back to positive HP, so you could take further actions.

Comment: @Tenryu: Good call on contingency, but false life would not work. Temp HP will not allow you to become conscious. [Can you gain Temporary Hit Points when unconscious?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/a/111599).

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Multi-classing a Wizard with Cleric/Druid 1 or Bard 6 would allow you to cast Cure Wounds as part of the Contingency. Also, a single-classed Bard 14/18 could have both Contingency and Cure Wounds as spells, so it can be done within RAW.

Comment: And the answer has already been edited for this. Ignore above.  :)

Comment: I'd like to note that technically half orcs have a similar feature where instead of falling to 0 they fall to 1 hp and are conscious.